# What Im doing wrong in this combinatoric problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

The task is to pick a team of 5 out of 17 boys and 13 girls, and there needs to be at least 2 of each.

I calculated the correct answer by taking $\binom{17}2\binom{13}3+\binom{17}3\binom{13}2=91936$.

When I tried different ways of imagining the problem I tried with typing it this way instead:

$$\binom{17}2\binom{13}2\binom{15+11}1$$ i.e. picking two from each gender then one out of the remaining, though this provides a different answer from above.

Where is my reasoning wrong on the latter?

Thanks!

Comment: {n \choose k} or \binom{n}{k}

Comment: @NeatMath was just about to comment that haha

Answer (score 2):

From the formulas, I am assuming that you want to pick $5$ people. The problem is that when you pick $1$ person from the $15+11$ pool, what if you, in another configuration, have **already** picked that person when you picked the $2$ from the boys and the $2$ girls? So you are essentially marking one of the people of the team as **special**(a capitan?). Notice then that if you divide by $3$ the new number, you get the right answer. This division is taking out the special property of the person.